# Vowel explanation

Tags: praat, phonetics

please i really need to finish my work as soon as possible. But i m confused with the vowel I have extracted. Those vowels I have extracted are eɪ/, /iː/, /aɪ/, /oʊ/, /u for long vowel      and /æ/, /ɛ/, /ɪ/, /ɒ/, /ʊ/ for short vowel.

Now in my work I want to work with them as vowel a, e, i, o, u. Can I change their name to vowel a, e, i, o, u? because they are respectively the vowel of a, e, i, o and u and what makes the difference is that the first one stands for long vowel and the second one for short vowel. Thank you for your help again

Answer (score 0):

So you want to deal with vowels in some form that doesn't matter and to do that you wanna store them, and that's your problem, do I get that right? So if you don't want to use the IPA letters which are weird and you want to replace them by normal ASCII chars, but you want a way to separate between long and short vowels, just store a short "u" like `u.` , just add a dot, and a long "o" like `o_`  or something like that. Or do I get that totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for your answer. I think you are understanding me. My big goal is to work with vowel "a" by comparing it with any vowel. But when i check the IPA symbols online, i was very confuse to find exactly the vowel "a". Even with some IPA symbol you can find a vowel like that "a". But now my question is how to get the vowel /a/ with the IPA symbols? But when i read on wekipedia and in any website they have written the both /eɪ/, /iː/, /aɪ/, /oʊ/, /u for long vowel and /æ/, /ɛ/, /ɪ/, /ɒ/, /ʊ/ for short vowel respectively for /a/,/e/,/i/,/o/ and /u/. So that is why i asked can i changed those IPA symbols as their ASCII. Beside, many works have done the studies of vowels /a/,/e/,/i/,/o/,/u/, but i do not no how or whether they changed the IPA symbols to /a/,/e/,/i/,/o/ and /u/ as i want to change? It was that my big confusion, tank you again for your clarification